# Resume interrupted bake in python

Tags: python

Given an interrupted (not paused) `bpy.ops.fluid.bake_data()`. What python command resumes the bake similar to pause/bake in GUI?

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.fluid.html